# Why my delete method is not working properly?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have troubles with my code in deleting a specific loan_id(primary key). My post method works good but my delete method doesn´t. Here's my code:

views.py:

```
class SolicitudPrestamoViewSet(viewsets.mixins.CreateModelMixin,viewsets.mixins.DestroyModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet): 
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = SucursalSerializer
    queryset = Prestamo.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'loan_id'

    def get(self, request, format=None,): 
        serializer = SucursalSerializer()
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def delete(self, request, loan_id, format=None):
        object = self.get_object(loan_id)
        object.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

models.py:

```
class Prestamo(models.Model):
    loan_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    loan_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
    choices = [('PERSONAL', 'PERSONAL'), ('HIPOTECARIO', 'HIPOTECARIO'), ('PRENDARIO', 'PRENDARIO')])
    loan_date = models.DateField()
    loan_total = models.IntegerField()
    customer_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'prestamo'
```

Answer (score 2):

In viewset you should use [`destroy`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) method to handle DELETE requests:

```
class SolicitudPrestamoViewSet(viewsets.mixins.CreateModelMixin,viewsets.mixins.DestroyModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet): 
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = SucursalSerializer
    queryset = Prestamo.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'loan_id'

    def destroy(self, request, loan_id):
        object = self.get_object(loan_id)
        object.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried it and now it doesn´t show me the delete method

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez what do you mean? Where it doesn't show?

Comment: don´t worry, it was my problem. I've resolved it (with the help of another user) by just deleting the def delete and leaving only the def get